Disable View Composer for Blade TestView?
The client wants the layouts.sidebar.blade.php to have a link for users with a certain role.
The AppServiceProvider boots a NotificationComposer for all (*) views.
The NotificationComposer has the following code
$view->with('unreadNotificationCount', count(request()->user()->unreadNotifications));
I want to write a test like the below, but recieve an error exception 'Attempt to read property "unreadNotifications" on null':
/** @test */
public function user_with_role_can_see_link_in_the_sidebar()
{
    $link = route('my-web.new-page');
    $response = $this->actingAs($this->userRole)->blade('layouts.sidebar');
    $response-assertSee($link);
}
/** @test */
public function normal_user_cannot_see_link_in_the_sidebar()
{
    $link = route('my-web.new-page');
    $response = $this->actingAs($this->user)->blade('layouts.sidebar');
    $response-assertDontSee($link);
}

I've rewritten to use http ->get() tests on only the homepage instead, but I'm not sure what the best way would be to test this? I know it's unlikely the homepage route will change, but wanted the test to be more specific.

To avoid the "unreadNotifications" error in your test, you can temporarily disable the view composer in your tests like this:
View::composer('*', function ($view) {
    // Do nothing or mock composer data
});

This prevents the NotificationComposer from running during the test, allowing you to focus on testing the sidebar view. Alternatively, you can mock the composer data:
View::composer('*', function ($view) {
    $view->with('unreadNotificationCount', 0);
});

This ensures the test runs without the exception.

To temporarily disable the view composer, View::composer('*', function ($view) { // Do nothing or mock composer data }); has to be added to each test method? I've added these lines after $link = route('my-web.new-page'); and I'm still getting the same error exception?

If you're still encountering the same error after adding the View::composer line, it might be because the NotificationComposer is still being applied before your override. To ensure it works, try adding the view composer override in the setUp method, which will run before each test.
Here's an updated approach:
1. Override in setUp Method
Place the View::composer override in the setUp method of your test class to apply it before each test.
    protected function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();

    // Disable NotificationComposer for all views in tests
    View::composer('*', function ($view) {
        // Mock the data if necessary
        $view->with('unreadNotificationCount', 0); 
    });
}

2. Then in Each Test
Proceed with your individual test cases as usual:
    /** @test */
public function user_with_role_can_see_link_in_the_sidebar()
{
    $link = route('my-web.new-page');
    $response = $this->actingAs($this->userRole)->blade('layouts.sidebar');
    $response->assertSee($link);
}

/** @test */

public function normal_user_cannot_see_link_in_the_sidebar()
{
    $link = route('my-web.new-page');
    $response = $this->actingAs($this->user)->blade('layouts.sidebar');
    $response->assertDontSee($link);
}

This will disable the NotificationComposer globally for all your tests, ensuring you don't get the null error.

the error exception 'Attempt to read property "unreadNotifications" on null' still persists. Moving the View::composer from the @test method to a setUp method made no difference to the call stack mentioned on @Raju Mondal answer's comment
